# Set work_mem for a native query in Spring data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to set work_mem for a native query that I am executing using Spring Data repository.

Tried having a native query as below

```
SET LOCAL WORK_MEM TO '8 MB';{Actual query}
```

But this did not work as postgres driver is splitting the query and executing them as two queries. As there is no result set for the for the first query the driver is throwing exception.

I am looking for a way to set work_mem for this specific query

Answer (score 1):

You would need to trigger the DDL statement before you invoke the actual query.

Make sure annotate your DDL `@Query` with additional `@Modifying` annotation. Without this, the engine would expect a result set.

With `@Modifying` you can execute `UPDATE, DELETE` and also in your case DDL statements.

Make sure you set your return type to `void`.

Comment: Thanks @Maciej Kowalski, I was looking for option where I can do everything with one repository method. But seems like the option you suggested is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Probably late but I have been trying to get Postgres Row Level Security working with our JPA project and I use the following to set a local session variable.  'Works on My Machine'.  (This is just a proof of concept snippet)

```
@GetMapping(path = "/rlstest")
@Transactional  // method must be annotated Transactional to tell JPA to use single session
public List<?> testRls() {
    // use nativequery to set variable
    Query x = em.createNativeQuery("set local usr.permissions='group1'");
    x.executeUpdate();

    // back to normal JPA world.  Because the method is Transactional the variable will still be set
    Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Testrls t");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```